# Make a SOAP API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, soap

I would like to make a SOAP API based on OpenAxisGroup Configuration. Can anyone help me with a gem or tutorial for the same? I have already seen wash_out, but would like a more frequently maintained and modified gem.
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/intridea/grape

Comment: Grape is for Restful API's, I want to make a SOAP API

Answer (score -1):

You can try Savon. It is a popular SOAP client for the Ruby programming language.

- [Github](https://github.com/savonrb/savon)
- [Documentation](http://savonrb.com/version2/)
- [RailCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to make a SOAP Server, not a client.

Comment: Savon is a client for *consuming* a SOAP service.